# AutoMapper to Map with nested property of List of array

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have a class A that I need to Map with class C

```
public class A{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<B> Address {get; set;}}


public class B{
    public string streetName{get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}}
```

I need to map this to Class C

```
public class C{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public List<MapAddressData> MapAddressData{get; set;}
    public DateTime DateCreated {get; set;}}

public class MapAddressData{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string streetName {get; set;}
   public int Number{get; set;}}
```

SO I need to use automapper to map List of Address in class A to List of MapAddressData in class C. I dont understand How to use for loop for map this because for a particular Name we well be having many address, n that has to mapped one by one to 'MapAddressData' class in class C. Is there way to implement this?

Comment: I've removed your Visual Studio tag because this question isn't about using the Visual Studio application.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Is there a way we can do using Automapper, instead of using loops as suggested (it is also working fine though), Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For example you have data for class A like

**Name=User1**

**Address1**

streetName = streetName1
Number = Number1

**Address2**

streetName = streetName2
Number = Number2

**Address3**

streetName = streetName3
Number = Number3

For multiple Names you have to make nested loop to access each and every data in class A object like, meanwhile consider we have object of class **MapAddressData** as mappedAddress.

```
foreach(var item from ClassAObject)
{
   mappedAddress.Name = item.Name;
   foreach(var address from item.Address)
   {
      mappedAddress.streetName = address.streetName;
      mappedAddress.Number= address.Number;
      >> Here you will be adding this mappedAddress objcect in mappedAddress from class C.

   }
}
```

Attaching code [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yw2AjmXP7gnNXNnyyr6cUjk52m-oxz1P/view?usp=sharing) just to get more clarification

Comment: I tried using your code, but it is creating a  list of mappedAddressList with same values in all the list elements. For example for 2 Listsofaddress , it is mapping and creating a list of 2 addresses but with same field values.

Comment: Can you share screenshot which shows your code and filled data as you mentioned?

Comment: It was an issue of value and reference type , I added this code "var mappedAddress = new()" inside the second  for loop and it worked.

Comment: will it possible to map if the class C is simply : public class C   {
    public int id        {get;    set;}  
    public MapAddressData MapAddressData     {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateCreated {get; set;}        }      Here instead of List I simply used MapAddressData..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way to do this, but you can configure AutoMapper like this:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<A, C>()
    .BeforeMap((src, _, ctx) => ctx.Options.Items[$"__{nameof(A)}"] = src)
    .ForMember(dst => dst.MapAddressData, mo => mo.MapFrom(src => src.Address));

cfg.CreateMap<B, MapAddressData>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, mo => mo.MapFrom(new MapAddressNameResolver()));
```

With `.BeforeMap` we are storing the source value in the mapping context items collection using the key `"__A"`.

Next, we tell AutoMapper that it should use the `Address` property on the source object to map `MapAddressData` on the destination object.

Then we create a map between `B` and `MapAddressData`. For the `Name` property of the destination object, we use a custom resolver: `MapAddressNameResolver` to retrieve the value:

```cs
private class MapAddressNameResolver : IValueResolver<B, MapAddressData, string>
{
    public string Resolve(B source, MapAddressData destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Options.Items.TryGetValue($"__{nameof(A)}", out var parent) 
                && parent is A sourceParent)
        {
            return sourceParent.Name;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Address cannot be mapped to MapAddressData indepdendently of A to C.");
    }
}
```

This looks at the mapping context items collection and tries to retrieve the value stored against the key `"__A"`. If it is indeed an instance of `A`, we return its `Name` property.

If any of these are incorrect, we throw an exception so that we know this has failed if someone tries to use this mapping in some other context in future without adding the appropriate support.

---

## Full example

```cs
public static void TestMethod()
{

    var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<A, C>()
            .BeforeMap((src, _, ctx) => ctx.Options.Items[$"__{nameof(A)}"] = src)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.MapAddressData, mo => mo.MapFrom(src => src.Address));

        cfg.CreateMap<B, MapAddressData>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, mo => mo.MapFrom(new MapAddressNameResolver()));
    });
    var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

    var sourceObject = new A()
    {
        Name = "bob",
        Address = new List<B>()
    {
        new B()
        {
            Number = 5,
            streetName = "bob street"
        },
        new B()
        {
            Number = 125,
            streetName = "somewhere street"
        }
    }
    };

    var mappedObject = mapper.Map<C>(sourceObject);
}

private class MapAddressNameResolver : IValueResolver<B, MapAddressData, string>
{
    public string Resolve(B source, MapAddressData destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Options.Items.TryGetValue($"__{nameof(A)}", out var parent) && parent is A sourceParent)
        {
            return sourceParent.Name;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Address cannot be mapped to MapAddressData indepdendently of A to C.");
    }
}
```